# Python multithreading, How is it using multiple Cores?

Tags: python, multithreading

I am running a multithreaded application(Python2.7.3) in a Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E7500  @ 2.93GHz. I thought it would be using only one core but using the "top" command I see that the python processes are constantly changing the core no. Enabling "SHOW THREADS" in the top command shows diffrent thread processes working on different cores.

Can anyone please explain this? It is bothering me as I know from theory that multithreading is executed on a single core.

Comment: "I know from theory that multithreading is executed on a single core." I'm not sure where you got that from. If that were true, that would be defeat one of the main reasons people use multiple threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, multithreading means *the inverse*, namely that multiple cores are being utilized (via threading) at the same time. CPython is indeed crippled when it comes to this, though whenever you call into C code (this includes parts of the standard library, but also extension modules like Numpy) the lock which prevents concurrent execution of Python code may be unlocked. You can still have multiple threads, they just won't be interpreting Python at the same time (instead, they'll take turns quite frequently). You also speak of "Python *processes*" -- are you confusing terminology, or is this "multithreaded" Python application in fact [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/multiprocessing.html)? *Of course* multiple Python processes can run concurrently.

However, from your wording I suspect another source of confusion. Even a single thread can run on multiple cores... just not at the same time. It is up to the operating system which thread is running on which CPU, and the OS scheduler does not necessarily re-assign a thread to the same CPU where it used to run before it was suspended (it's beneficial, as David Schwartz notes in the comments, but not vital). That is, it's perfectly normal for a single thread/process to jump from CPU to CPU.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am using only the threading module in CPython. I had the flawed idea that one thread runs only in a single core.

Comment: Actually, many OS schedulers do try to re-schedule a thread on the same CPU it was last running on. They do this for two reasons: First, there's a chance that some data will still be in one of the CPU caches. Second, to avoid having too much conflict on a global scheduler lock, per-core scheduler structures with their own locks are used. As a result, moving a thread from one core to another requires more processing (moving it from one core's thread set to another's with separate locks on each) than re-running it on the same core.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Very interesting, thank you. I'll tone that sentence down.

Comment: @delnan I think you meant to write: "the lock which prevents concurrent execution of Python code *is lifted*" (missing that last part, kinda important :) )

Answer (score -1):

Threads are designed to take advantage of multiple cores when they are available. If you only have one core, they'll run on one core too. :-)

There's nothing to be concerned about, what you observe is "working as intended".